# ButtonInteraction.awaitModalSubmit() registers multiple times

Tags: discord.js

I have an **interaction** that comes with an embed and some components (buttons). When someone clicks on any of these buttons, a Modal is shown.

However, it happens that if I:

- press the button
- close the Modal window
- and press the button again
- but this time actually submit info

it ends up recording as if there were two submits. It happens as many times as I open and close the Modal without giving any information. That is:

- I open and close 6 times
- and then open again and submit
- 7 submits will be recorded

I tried using `.deferReply()`, but it just generated more errors. Most of the solutions I searched and tried also only generated more errors.

```
const collector = res.createMessageComponentCollector(
   {
      componentType: ComponentType.Button,
      // 1,000ms = 1s / 60,000ms => 1min
      time: 1000*60
   }
);

collector.on('collect', async i => new Promise(async (res, reject) => {
   const modal = createTicketModal(i.customId);

   i.showModal(modal);

   await i.awaitModalSubmit({
      time: 60000,
      filter: (modalSubmitI) => {
         return modalSubmitI.customId === 'input-ticket-info';
      }
   })
   .then((modalSubmitI) => {
       modalSubmitI.channel.send('modal submitted')
   }).catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
       return null
   })
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an anonymous function, so basically, an anonymous function runs like this:

```
const nameOfTheFuntion = (...params) => { //response }
```

You are using it like this:

```
const nameOfTheFunction = (...params) => new Promise((...) => { response })
```

I don't know if there's any other problem here (or if it is a problem), but try it.

Best regards, TomG

Comment: I tested it, but the error remains. What I think happens is that the `awaitModalSubmit` is not reset. So when I click the button again, the  `awaitModalSubmit` from the interaction with the button passed still exists and waits for the submit. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Try use the word `return`  in `modalSubmitI.channel.send('modal submitted')`.
So it should be `return modalSubmitI.channel.send('modal submitted')`.
Tell me if it works,
Best regards, TomG